# Job stay in pending list after processed

Tags: laravel, queue, horizon

I am running Laravel 8, horizon 5.4
After I initiate the job, it processes successfully as it should, but in the Horizon dashboard it stays pending list, it does not move to the completed or failed list, after timeout(60 minutes) it disappears from the pending list.

Horizon Dashboard (Pending List)
[image: Horizon Dashboard (Pending List)]

Horizon process status from terminal
[image: Horizon process status]

Horizon status from Redis

[image: Horizon status from Redis]

Horizon Configuration

```
    'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => [env('QUEUE_NAME','default')],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 3,
            'tries' => 3,
        ],
    ],
```

Redis configuration in queue

```
    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue'  => env('QUEUE_NAME', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
    ],
```

Googled a lot with no luck, maybe I am not searching with the right keyword.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you figured out the issue, I am at a similar place. My jobs never move out of pending status. When I click to view details it shows completed_at timestamp which means they were completed.

Answer (score -1):

I have samma issue. The jobs stay in both `Pendings jobs` and `Completed jobs`. These jobs have the same id and the same completed_at timestamp. Not alla the jobs stay in both. It is only a few jobs that stay in i both.